# canvas based color picker on another canvas element

Tags: javascript

i have made a canvas having width and height of the window.i also made a color picker based on canvas which has a onmousemove event to get pixel information so that i can use that color to draw on my main canvas.individually the onmousemove for picker works but as soon as i put it on the corner side and gave it a fixed position accroding to  my main drawing canvas, it's mouse event doesnt work.even i can draw beneath the color picker.i tried to set a z-index property for the color picker ,though it did'nt work.how can i solve this problem and make my picker work fine

hope i make my problem clear :(

if you run my code i hope you will understand the problem

```
<html>
<head>
<title>a drawing board</title>

</head>
<body style="margin:0;">

<script>
var radius=10;
var colorit="";
var lines;
var x,y;
var cna=false;
var i=0;

function canvloder(){

var canvas=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
canvas.style.backgroundColor="yellow";

}
function nowdraw(e){

cna=true;

}
function drawit(e){

if(cna){

var ctx=document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d");
x=e.clientX;
y=e.clientY;
if(i==0){
ctx.lineWidth=2*radius;
ctx.lineTo(x,y);
ctx.stroke();

}
if(i>0){

ctx.fillStyle=colorit;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
i=0;

}
ctx.fillStyle=colorit;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth=2*radius;
ctx.strokeStyle=colorit;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x,y);
}

}
function cannotdraw(){
cna=false;
i++;

}


window.onmousedown=nowdraw;
window.onmousemove=drawit;
window.onmouseup=cannotdraw;

function pencolor( colname){
colorit=colname;

}

function therad(capture){
if(capture=="increase"){
radius++;
}
if(capture=="decrease"){
radius--;
}
}
function gotClicked(val){
radius=val;
}

function itsmycanvas(){


  var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');



        var k=0,j=0,a=255,r=0;g=0;
        newCanvas.width = 256;
        newCanvas.height = 256;
        newCanvas.style.position="fixed";
        newCanvas.style.top="30px";
        newCanvas.style.right="0px";
            newCanvas.style.border ='2px solid black';
            newCanvas.style.zIndex="2000";

        for(r=0;r<256;r++){

        for(g=0;g<256;g++){




               var context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');

                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(k,j);
                  context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ','+a+')';
                  context.lineTo(k+90,j);

                context.stroke();
                context.closePath();

                  j++;
                   if(j==256){
                   if(k<=256-90){
                        k=k+90;
                        }
                        j=0;
                        }

                a--;
                if(a==0){a=150;}



            }
        }


        var d=document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);
        d.addEventListener("mouseover",myfunc,false);   
        }
        function myfunc(e) {


    var imageData = context.getImageData(e.clientX, e.clientY, 1, 1);
    var red = imageData.data[0];
    var green = imageData.data[1];
    var blue = imageData.data[2];
    var alpha = imageData.data[3];
   alert(red+"  "+green+"  "+blue);
}





window.onload=canvloder;
</script>

<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
<div style="position:fixed;top:0px;background-color:grey;display:block;width:100%;">
<div style="float:right;left:50px;">Radius <span title="increase width"style="background-color:white;padding:5px;margin-right:5px;" onCLick="therad('increase');"> + </span><span title="decrease width" style="padding:5px;background-color:white;margin-right:5px;" onClick="therad('decrease');"> - </span></div>
<div  title="red" style="background-color:red;width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:30px;float:left;" onClick="pencolor('red');"></div>
<div  title="black"style="background-color:black;width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:40px;float:left;" onClick="pencolor('black');"></div>
<div  title="pink"style="background-color:pink;width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:40px;float:left;" onClick="pencolor('pink');"></div>
<div  title="green"style="background-color:green;width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:40px;float:left;" onClick="pencolor('green');"></div>
<div  title="eraser"style="background-color:white;width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:40px;float:left;text-align:centre;" onClick="pencolor('yellow');">clr</div>
<div  title="blue"style="background-color:blue;width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:40px;float:left;" onClick="pencolor('blue');"></div>
</div>
<select style="position:fixed;top:0px;left:300px;">radius
<option onClick="gotClicked(15);">15px</option>
<option onClick="gotClicked(10);" selected>10px</option>
<option onClick="gotClicked(6);">8px</option>
<option onClick="gotClicked(5);">5px</option>
<option onClick="gotClicked(3);">3px</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="itsmycanvas();" value="SHOW CANVAS" style="position:fixed;top:400px;right:0px;">
</body>
</html>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jZwv/1/)

(fiddle not working as it should be :\don't know what's wrong )

Comment: its working.. change the onload to no-wrap in body in fiddle

Comment: you mean window.nowrap?? can u give any suggestion on my problem stated above?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the body tag from html and add the option no warp in body`(option of fiddle)`
it seems working

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsaleem/5jZwv/10/)**